# Insert textbox input into an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to know if its possible to insert textfield input directly into an array, then insert the same values into mysql database.  This is an idea I would like to use, but dont want to waste time with it if its not possible.  I am still learning PHP

```
if($Number == 1){
    echo '<table border="0">';
    echo '<th>'.'Attribute'.'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.'Score'.'</th>';

    echo '<tr>';
    //First Form
    echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" size="35" name="Attributes[]">'.'</td>';   
    echo '<td>'.'<select id="select55" name ="score[]">
        <option>-select-</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>1</option>
        </select>'.'</td>';            
    echo '</tr>'; 
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Why not try it? And yes that's possible. But sounds wrong for so many reasons.

Comment: are you using form... ? And what do you mean by directly into array ...Please be more elaborative.. of course it is possible but I want to know what you exactly mean .. ?

Comment: Hi guys, yes I am using forms.  I let the user choose the number of entries they would to capture, then I only display those number of forms.  From there on I would like to store their input into the database.  I cant think of any other way to do it except for storing it into the array, then run through the array to insert those inputs into the database.  What is the better way to do this ?

Comment: @tlenss is it bad practice ?

Comment: @user1783675 Well it's not really clear what you are trying to do. But yes i would consider this bad practice. But their might actually be a good reason to store it... i just can't think of any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure. Are you saying that you want to allow the user to enter any number of scores in one form? If you want to use pure php and html the way to go about this is using two forms. You would set it up kind of like this.

**Form**

```
<?php 
if (empty($_GET["entries"]))
{ 
?>

<p>How many entries do you want to make?</p>
<form action="sadg.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="entries" placeholder="Number of entries" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_entries" />
</form>

<?php 
}
else
{
    //Second form
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        //Process form
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';

        for ($count = 0; $count < $_GET["entries"]; $count++)
        {
            echo '<input type="text" name="scores">';
        }

        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"></form>';
    }
}
?>
```

Hopefully that makes sense. You first prompt them to make entries, save that number as a page parameter, and then display the appropriate amount of forms based on that page parameter.